# Jump to part of page through URL

Tags: url

Consider the following link:

> https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=USDT-neo

I need to somehow manipulate the URL so that when it's clicked, it jumps straight to the `Order Book` section of the webpage.

I've tried finding the ID for that part and appending it the URL, but that wouldn't work because the ID isn't generated when you enter the page through the normal URL.

Does anyone know how to manipulate the link so it jumps straight to the `Order Book` part?

To be clear, I do not want to use JS. I want to have a pure link which I can click and will take me to the Order Book.

I need this so I could take a screenshot of the chart using a node module called `Pageres`.

If anyone has any different idea as of how to download the chart of the Order Book to a png, it'd be awesome (Or even more generally, download a chart of any cryptocurrency's Order Book to a png, using any website).

Many thanks,

~Yuval

Comment: javascript ????

Comment: No, just somehow change the URL.

Comment: `Pure link` without JavaScript will most probably open as it is ( the same link you opened) . the only possible way to make it open another URL is if you handle it in back end

Comment: Do you have an idea as of how I could take a screenshot of the Order Book page (with the node module specified)

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you can handle the click in the following way:

```
<a id="fake_link" class="fake-link" href="https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=USDT-neo">Click me</a>

<script>
    var elem = document.getElamentById("fake_link");
    elem.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = "YOUR NEW LOCATION";
    },false);
</script>
```

Comment: I've clarified my question ^^

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, all you need is add the id of the part of the page that you want to go to. The section you mention starts with:

```
<div class="row" id="rowTable">
```

So all you have to do is add `#rowTable` to your URL:

https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=USDT-neo#rowTable

That will instruct the browser to look for the part of the page with the id that you mention.

But you are right, the id part of the page is generated after it is loaded. In your case it only works if you change the URL with the page already loaded.

You could try using an intermediate page with a bit of `javascript` that will first load the page, then jump to the part you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location.hash property in java script to grab the hash of the current page
use is like this:

```js
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash == "#tabChartOrderBook"){
//function to switch tab
}
```

I wrote this for your url
https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=USDT-neo#tabChartOrderBook
and as I said in code your url hash is #tabChartOrderBook

Comment: I have tried that, but that sadly did not work.
If you click the link you can see it goes to the chart, and not the Order Book.
I've clarified the question.